# Facing issue after implementing Sharing Test Context between Cucumber Step Definitions using PicoContainer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, picocontainer

I have implemented a shared Test Context between Cucumber Step Definitions using PicoContainer.

Please find the complete code which I have written in the below shared drive.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bBxOJDW7auqN_CX9tc0KEDo-TiPzew6m/view?usp=sharing

Before implementing PicoContainer i have only one Step definition class after implementing it I created two separate step def classes for Home Page and Login Page.

Please find the below feature which i am automating. After i implemented share Test Context only first scenario is running successfully,  while running Second scenario New browser is opening then failing it with NullPointerException.

```
Feature: Login Action

 Scenario Outline: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User Navigate to LogIn Page
    And User enters "<username>" and "<password>"
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully
    Examples:
    | username   | password |
    | username@gmail.com | userpassword |


Scenario: Successful LogOut
    When User LogOut from the Application
    Then Message displayed LogOut Successfully
```

Please help me to fix this issue..

Comment: You will get better feedback if you format your question.

Comment: Please paste (and format) your code here. Would love to help you, but I'm not going to download a rar to do so.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I don't think people want to debug your whole project for you.